Copy from databricks to azure using sql
I'm pretty new to Databricks. I want to write a sql query to move the data from table to external stage(azure blob). Is there any way of doing that?
I can see that there is an option to copy into table from external locations, but I couldn't find it's vice versa.
Can anyone please help me with the same.
PS: I don't want to create any notebook to do the same, as I want to run SQL query from some other service ( not from databricks).


PS: I don't want to create any notebook to do the same, as I want to run SQL query from some other service ( not from databricks).

If your source and target are delta tables, then you can use COPY INTO to achieve your requirement.
You can check this documentation1  and documentation2 to know more about it. But you need to run the query in databricks for this.
OR, If the target is a file in the blob, you can try ADF copy activity as a workaround to get the desired results.
You can follow this documentation steps to configure copy activity in ADF.
Give your query in the copy activity source.

If it's a file, In the sink give your desired file type and give Blob storage file path and make sure the Row delimiter is a single character if it's a csv file.

Enable the staging and debug the pipeline and the result file will be generated with your source table data.

